# Owl carousel - extra dot in homepage in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have odd problem with owl carousel in wordpress. I have the same carousel in few pages and at homepage it shows me 4 dots(should be 3) and at another pages it shows 3 (as it should be). I tried to switch carousels between pages but at homepage always shows extra dot.
Maybe someone already met this problem?

Comment: Did you call different slider on different page. i mean you have created multiple sliders with owl carousel and used different on each page?

Comment: yes, but at some pages I use slider from homepage. Ex. Homepage - homepage slider (4 dots), Page 2 - homepage slider(3 dots) , Page 3 - homepage slider(3 dots). I tried with other sliders - at homepage always add one extra dot

Comment: ayone had the same problem?